# Get the value of each field that updated in updating operation

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i want get value of field after update,
for example i have two table

```
table1:  ID       Price          UserID         type 

table2:  IDLog    ID(FK table1)  OldPrice
```

and i update Price in table 1:

```
UPDATE table1
SET    Price = '1111'
WHERE  TYPE = 1
```

now i want befor every update get value ID table1 and insert into table2,
how i get value every field??

Comment: Are you using the `entity framework`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO [`FOR UPDATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) is the way to go. That way you can contain all logging logic inside your DB.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do it is using trigger on table1 (SQL Server side of course).

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_update ON table1 FOR UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO table2 (IDLog, OldPrice)
       SELECT ID, Price
       FROM deleted
          INNER JOIN inserted ON
               deleted.ID = inserted.ID
               deleted.Price <> inserted.Price
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use output clause:

```
update table1
output inserted.ID into table2
set Price='1111' where type=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data to table2 before updating.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT ID, Price from table1
WHERE  TYPE = 1

--Update table1 after inserting
UPDATE table1
SET    Price = '1111'
WHERE  TYPE = 1
```

Other way to do is to create an update trigger for table1, which inserts the updated data to table2.